# create a div that has a state changed when a click is registered outside it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom checkbox group input that is build using antd in react(`Typescript`).

This is in a `div` whose state (visibility) is controlled using a state, and is shown on the click of a button.
I need an event listener that will modify the state when a click is registered outside this state so that I can hide this.

Tried writing a lot of hooks but unable to figure this out. My div gets hidden also when I click to select/unselect the checkboxes inside the div.

```
<div className="relative">
      <Button
        className=" rounded-l-lg bg-white text-base mt-3 min-w-[175px] px-4 h-auto"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        {getEntitySelectorPlaceholderText()}
        <FaChevronDown className="ml-1" />
      </Button>
      {visible && (
        <div className="absolute z-10 bg-white border-gray-200 mt-2 shadow">
          <CheckboxGroup
            className="flex justify-center flex-col items-start ml-3 mt-0 min-w-[165px] pt-3 px-3"
            options={[{ label: t('allChannels'), value: 'allChannels' }]}
            onChange={handleSelectAll}
            value={entityItems.length === NO_OF_CHANNELS ? ['allChannels'] : []}
          />
          <CheckboxGroup
            className="flex justify-center flex-col items-start ml-3 mt-0 min-w-[165px] pb-3 px-3"
            options={[
              { label: t('gift'), value: 'gift' },
              { label: t('batch'), value: 'batch' },
              { label: t('partner'), value: 'partner' },
              { label: t('webOrder'), value: 'webOrder' },
              { label: t('inAppOrder'), value: 'inAppOrder' },
              { label: t('partnerOrder'), value: 'partnerOrder' },
            ]}
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={checkedItems}
            defaultValue={Object.entries(entities || {})
              .filter(([_, value]) => {
                return value
              })
              .map(([key]) => {
                return key
              })}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
```

Have tried it on chat gpt and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the ref to the parent div. `<div className="relative" ref={dropDownRef}>` and watch the mouse-down event listener.

````
  const dropDownRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

  const handleClickOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    if (dropDownRef.current && !dropDownRef.current.contains(event.target as Node)) {
      setVisible(false)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside)
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside)
    }
  }, []) ```
````